# Installing Chocolatey so that it can install packages as admin level

Tags: windows-10, chocolatey

If Chocolatey, a Windows package manager, is installed using Administrator privileges, does it need Admin privileges to install other apps?

If so, is there a way to allow Chocolatey to self-escalate Admin privileges when it needs to install an app that requires admin-level privileges?

Comment: Unless software is being installed to `%AppData%` or `%LocalAppData%`, it _always_ requires Admin privs.

Answer (score -1):

You're talking about Admin privileges when *running processes*, as it doesn't matter how you *installed files*, the executable would have to gain Admin privileges when started by the regular user.

The solution is to have a service [generally, a process that is automatically started at boot with admin privileges] and have `choco` delegate the installation to that service when run by a user, which is what the recent feature [Agent Service](https://chocolatey.org/docs/features-agent-service) does (Business Editions only).